# Populate DataTable from array with specific columns

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm trying to populate DataTable for Google Charts (visualization API) and I have a problem with the loop. Function should get the data from php via ajax and when sucess, add items to the DataTable.

```
  $.each(res, function (i, element) {
    var cust = element["Customer"];
    var prog = element["progr"];
    var pm = element["pm"];
    var startd = element["StartD"];
    var endd = element["EndD"];
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Customer');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Customer');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Project Manager');
    data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
    data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');
    for(var j = 0; j < res.length; j++) 
      data.addRow(
        [cust[j], cust[j], pm[j], new Date('2020', '0', '12'), new Date('2020', '0', '12'), null, prog[j] *100, null]);
```

I was tring with different setups and instead of addRow with addRows[] as well.
The result with above code is, that it splits the first Customer name into rows.

[image]

There are multiple rows in the array. I would like to add all of them to the DataTable and then pass it to the chart.

Comment: will you please share a sample of the data (`res`)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I can close this topic now, as I know what was the issue - I've separated vars and addColumn and just moved only addRow to $.each:       $.each(res, function (i, element) {
        data.addRow(
          [element["empl"], element["emplid"].toString(), (element["fte1"]).toString(), parseFloat(element["cost1"].toFixed(2)), parseFloat(element["cost2"].toFixed(2)), parseFloat(element["cost3"].toFixed(2))]
        );